# Rails how to organize views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one app with two different views per controller.

So I want to have `mysite.com/old/accounts` should be rendered old templates.

At `mysite.com/new/accounts` renders new templates.

I think I need to do it through `params` in `application controller`?

or maybe `mysite.com/accouts?layout=new` or old ?

How to do it?

Comment: But what changes is only the templates or what happens in the controller action also changes depending on it? And is only that route? How are the routes set up?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a namespace in your routes called `old` with a an
   `account resource`.
2. Create a folder in controllers called `old` with an `accounts_controller` inside the folder
3. Create a folder in your views called `old` with your old account views